# Custom Post Type with Different Sets of Post Content?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "Industry" and want to allow for a given Industry post to have different sets of post content depending on "Region". The post type would have a series of fields defined to record statistics, and these statistics would vary by region. So, for example, there would be a post for "Manufacturing" with basic statistics recorded in fields for each region. Thus, I can create a custom taxonomy for "Region" with terms for "Region A" and "Region B". My question is how best can I configure the custom post type to have different post content for each region? There are three routes I can think of:

1. I just create separate Industry posts for each region and assign each post the appropriate taxonomy term (Region A or Region B.) The downside of this approach is that each Industry will have redundant posts (i.e. two for each industry) and wouldn't have a relationship to one another unless via a separate taxonomy or relationship field.
2. I set up Industry as a hierarchical post type, have a parent-level post for the general Industry info, and child posts corresponding to each region. From an organizational standpoint, this might be the best route, but there's still redundancy with the parent post.
3. I set up an ACF repeater field for the Industry post type to create separate rows of data corresponding to each region, thus allowing for a single Industry post to contain data for both regions. This is probably the least desirable route as the instances of Industry data for each region would not exist as actual (queryable) posts.

Thus, I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for a different approach to create different sets of post content for a given post type- any ideas are most appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by different sets of data? Do you mean different post content? Can you be more specific/literal so that it's clearer what you meant? This problem is described only with technical language and has no surrounding context to put it into place, making certain things ambiguous murky and unclear. My current thoughts though are that your "industry" is too broad and that more sub-division or content organisation work is needed, posts have a canonical URL and you should always show the same content or "data" for the same URL

Comment: Extra context would be helpful here as without it it's really difficult to suggest how to adjust your post types, or if a completely different solution is needed, or a misunderstanding has happened. Use the `Edit` link to clarify what you meant and add context and make the question more specific so that it's answerable with hard concrete facts. At the moment it's been made too abstract to answer

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback @TomJNowell - I just edited the question and provided an example, please let me know if this is now sufficiently clear. By "data" I do mean post content- so each Industry post would have fields for statistics, but these values would vary based on the two regions, so I'm trying to figure out how best to reflect this requirement in the post type structure/organization..